# MySQL INSERT and SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() in one line

Tags: mysql, sql, case-statement, last-insert-id

I was wondering if there was a way to change this statement

```
INSERT INTO [table] VALUES ([values]);
SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Into a single line. Something such as

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN ( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM [table] WHERE id=1 ) > 0 
THEN 'false' 
WHEN ( INSERT INTO [table] VALUES ([values]) )
THEN LAST_INSERT_ID()
END INTO @myid;
```

(which could effectively be written in a single line)

Would the `WHEN ( INSERT INTO ...)` statement is attempted, will it return a value that we can check?

Will it also execute the `INSERT` even if it is within a `CASE` statement?

Comment: No, you can't use an `INSERT` statement as a subquery.

Comment: You could do what you want in a stored procedure.

Comment: Would something like this help you? `INSERT INTO table (id,....) VALUES (1234,........) ON DUPLICATE KEY id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` => If it existed or not doesn't matter: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will hold the last inserted id or the already existing id. If not: what is it you're trying to accomplish with your functionality? There may be easier other ways.

Comment: I came across this function when trying to determine the best answer to this problem. Im slightly confused as to why 'id' is passed to 'LAST_INSERT_ID'. Would that not then perform an update on the row? I would like to not perform any insert if the key already exists.

Comment: I've given it a test and it looks like it performs as expected. So its basically setting the LAST_INSERT_ID() as the id that is returned... as I understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had no choice but to split the code to two lines using on of the suggestions in the comments.

```
INSERT INTO table (id,....) VALUES (1234,........) ON DUPLICATE KEY id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID into @myid
```